# Why ubuntu doesn't start from the first bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I guess I accidentally created some subshell and realized that I can't reach Conda anymore. Then, I did some search and used `bash`. And now I'm able to reach Conda again. But the problem is now every time I open the Ubuntu terminal, I have to `bash` once. I guess `pstree` would explain the situation better than me. I don't know why it doesn't start from the first bash anymore. [image: here]

[image]

I think before this all happened `pstree` was like this:
[image]

Comment: What does `echo $0` say before and after you type `bash`? My guess is that the first case is a login shell (which will read your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`) whereas the second is a non-login shell that reads your `.bashrc`. Is this WSL by any chance?

Comment: Yeah I am using WSL2. I also added the results of `echo $0` before and after `bash`.

Comment: Do not beg specific volunteers for assistance. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable. When you question is answerable, and somebody knows the answer, then somebody will answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently WSL starts bash as a *login shell*. Among other things, this means it reads (in order of preference) your `~/.bash_profile` and `.profile` files. Your subsequently invoked `bash` command is invoked as an *interactive non-login* shell and hence ignores those startup files and instead reads your `~/.bashrc` (which is presumably where you have done your conda setup).

Regular desktop Ubuntu tries to make non-login and login shells more similar by adding a section to the default `~/.profile` that

- checks if the shell is bash (not sh, or zsh, or some other shell)
- if so sources the user's `~/.bashrc` file

WSL appears to provide its own minimal `~/.profile` that does not do this - but if it bothers you, you could

- backup your current file: `cp ~/.profile ~/.profile.bak`
- copy the default Ubuntu one from the `/etc/skel` directory: `cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/`

or (possibly better), create a `~/.bash_profile` if you haven't already got one, and source `~/.bashrc` from there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution from a
[Github post](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2067#issuecomment-299622057). Although this is not the real solution since it doesn't fix the 2*[{init}] problem, it does the work.